# make label visible when invalid data entered

Tags: c#, winforms

As an exercise in creating Windows Applications in C# I have to create a simple calculator. During the button Event I am expected to use TryParse to grab data from Text Boxes and check validity.

The issue I am having is when invalid data is detected label1 is supposed to become visible, change font color and display a message. This is not working. If I use a Message Box, it will pop up, and the label updates. With Message Box commented out, the label stays hidden and the app will lock up when I input bad data during testing.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ushort operand1;
    ushort operand2;

    while((UInt16.TryParse(txtOperand1.Text, out operand1) & UInt16.TryParse(txtOperand2.Text, out operand2)) == false)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("not number");
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label1.Text = "Value must be numeric and > 0";
    }

    int result;

    result = operand1 + operand2;

    label1.Visible = true;
    label1.Text = string.Format("{0:N}", result).ToString();
}
```

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code snippet?

Comment: To change the appearance of the label the form engine should have a chance to apply your changes. If you never exit from this code then you will never see the changes. A call to MessageBox allows the form engine to apply your changes

Comment: See also: [How to: Display Error Icons for Form Validation with the Windows Forms ErrorProvider Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/display-error-icons-for-form-validation-with-wf-errorprovider)

Comment: First `&` is bit-wise operator and  `&&` is logic operator. Second, `while` is used in Console App together with `ReadLine`, your while loop blocks processing of `winform` message loop, instead of it, exit the `btnAdd_Click` by using `if-else`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program is locking up on invalid data because of your use of the `while` loop.  You should be using just an `if\else` statement instead, because you want your label to either display the error message or the calculated result.

Change your code to something like:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ushort operand1;
    ushort operand2;

    if((UInt16.TryParse(txtOperand1.Text, out operand1) &&
        UInt16.TryParse(txtOperand2.Text, out operand2)) == false)
    {
        // MessageBox.Show("not number");
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        label1.Text = "Value must be numeric and > 0";
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Visible = true;
        label1.Text = string.Format("{0:N}", operand1 + operand2).ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing the `while()` loop on the UI thread, which means it is too busy in the loop to process your inputs and therefore hangs.

A quick hack would be to put `Application.DoEvents()` inside the loop. This tells the UI thread to stop what it's doing for a moment and process pending events. I'd really suggest not doing this though as it's probably the worst way you could keep your UI responsive.

Why do you need a loop in the first place though? Just do the check once when the button is clicked and then give the user their feedback.

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ushort operand1;
    ushort operand2;

    bool validInput = UInt16.TryParse(txtOperand1.Text, out operand1) && 
                      UInt16.TryParse(txtOperand2.Text, out operand2);

     if(!validInput)
     {
         // MessageBox.Show("not number");
         label1.Visible = true;
         label1.ForeColor = Color.Red;
         label1.Text = "Value must be numeric and > 0";
     }
     else
     {
         int result;
         result = operand1 + operand2;
         label1.Visible = true;
         label1.Text = string.Format("{0:N}", result).ToString();
     }  
}
```